# MongoDB: unable to load driver on PHP

Tags: php, macos, mongodb, osx-mavericks, php-extension

I'm trying to make [mongo-php-driver](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-php-driver) work with **PHP 5.5.7** on **OS X 10.9.1** but I came to a dead end, I've tried everything I could possibly find and nothing works...

Everything compiles just fine, but PHP doesn't load the extension and gives a really odd error:

```
Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-zts-20121212/mongo.so' - dlopen(/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-zts-20121212/mongo.so, 9): Symbol not found: _core_globals
  Referenced from: /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-zts-20121212/mongo.so
  Expected in: flat namespace
 in Unknown on line 0
```

I've checked about thread safety and architecture issues but everything is just fine, both extension and PHP are thread safe and 64bits.

I also checked if there was any issues with the binaries, like `phpize` and `php-config`, but everything seems to be just fine...

I really don't know what to do, anyone has any clue?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This issue is only happening on the [lastest version](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-php-driver/tree/6e4108d98912483f7e37523944df0518c887806e).

I just tried with the [1.4.5](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-php-driver/tree/861d4b8c70accf09e4481d004cd52572287e36a2) and everything went just fine!

Comment: How did you do it? I run osx 1.6.8, MAMP 2.2 with PHP 5.5.3, mongo (driver) 1.4.5 stable (got it with PECL install) and getting incompatibility of API's: Module compiled with module API=20090626
PHP compiled with module API=20121212

Comment: @ljgww you're probably experience two different APIs because when the driver is compiled it's using phpize and php-config from the original PHP bundled with OS X. try running `which phpize`, it's probably not pointing to the one that MAMP provides...

Comment: I had to downgrade php to 5.3.27 in order to make it work (compatible apis). Luckily MAMP comes with plenty of different php versions. 

Tried driver for windows version too and it works much better. But there are more precompiled binaries than for Mac. Publishing binaries for mac for more recent APIs would help a lot.

Comment: strange... the 1.4.5 driver is working fine for me on PHP 5.5.7, but I used `phpize`, I've never tried `pecl`.

Answer (score 0):

gibatronic, as far as I understand, you have compiled this driver for 5.5.7. I tried to use existing precompiled binary provided online (and discovered last compatible php version)

Comment: yea... different ways to achieve the same thing. that's why is so ease for me to get lost on such things!